# Google ドライブ に保存した画像を、自分のserverへ配置したWebページで表示できますか？

Tags: 画像

やりたいことが2つあります。
私が借りているserver　をSとします。容量少ないです。

**A. 「私」が「S以外」へ画像保存して、「S」へ配置したWebページで表示したい。**

**B.「任意のuser」が「S以外」へ画像保存して、「S」へ配置したWebページで表示したい。**

---

**試したこと**
私は「Amazon Photos」を借りているので、そこでA.を出来ないか試してみたのですが、画像表示するためにはログインが必要なようで、希望した使い方は出来ませんでした

---

**質問**
Google ドライブ なら、やりたいことが出来ますか？

Comment: この記事あたりでしょうか。[Google Drive に保存した画像を直接呼び出せるURLの取得](https://qiita.com/arribux/items/0394968fa318d9309d33), [Google Driveの画像をブログに埋め込む](https://journal.lampetty.net/entry/embed-images-on-google-drive), [GoogleドライブにあるファイルをWebページとして公開したい！](https://otona-life.com/2019/05/13/12421/), [Googleドライブの画像をimgタグで表示する方法、表示速度、見え方](https://mylife-blog.com/google-drive-yahoo-box-img)

Comment: 任意のユーザーがウイルスを保存してあなたの web ページから感染拡大するなんてシナリオも考えられます。セキュリティ的に要検討かもしれないっす。

Comment: Google アカウント自体は無料で作成できるので、まずは自分で試すべきではないでしょうか？